# What does W A M mean in Milnor's book?

Tags: notation, soft-question, differential-topology

Slowcoach felt sure he had finally crawled into a position from where he could haul himself through *Topology from the Differential Viewpoint* by John Milnor. Imagine his humility when, on the very first page of the book, his march to victory was gunned down by a simple piece of notation.

> $ \mathbf {Definition} $ A subset $ M \subset R^k $ is called a *smooth manifold* of *dimension $m$* if each $x \in M$ has a neighborhood $W$ A $M$ that is diffeomorphic to an open subset $U$ of the euclidean space $R''$.

Here is a screen shot of the fly in the ointment – I didn't know how to render it using MathJax so used instead the easy option of capital letter that looked like it.

[image: fly in oitment]

[And a screenshot of the brief prelude to the definition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y0jw.jpg)

So there we have it: what does the A in WAM mean?

Comment: Given that the font of that A looks rather different from the surrounding symbols, I wonder if it is an issue with your reading device not having appropriate fonts installed?

Comment: probably should be $\subseteq$

Comment: It is most likely a mis-render of $\subseteq$.

Comment: It is the intersection, based on the preview of the text on Amazon.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I'll delete this Q.

Comment: @Slowcoach This question is perfectly well on topic.

Answer (score 5):

I am posting this as an answer because I cannot post images in comments.  However, I believe that this question is off-topic for Math SE, as question is ultimately the result of a rendering error, and is not mathematical in nature.

This is a problem with the rendering of the font in the version of the text you are reading.  The top Google hit (in my Google bubble) is a [.pdf document](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2017/MilnorDiff.pdf) which contains this error:

[image]

However, in the preview of the same text on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691048339), the passage is rendered as

[image]

I suspect that the document you are reading is an OCR'd version of the original text which has not been proofread or copy edited to catch these kinds of mistakes.  Note, also (for example) that the $\varepsilon$ is not rendered correctly in the same line, and that $R^m$ is rendered at $R''$.  I would suggest that you find a different copy of this text.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll delete the question since you say it is off-topic.

Comment: It's not an epsilon rendered incorrectly, the context suggests it's an 'is element of' $\in$ rendered as a little capital E or as epsilon.

Comment: @CiaPan I am very aware of what the symbol means in that context.  However, in Milnor's text, it is an epsilon, which is used to denote membership (with [historical precedent](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/is-the-symbol-for-set-membership-in-derived-from-greek-letter-epsilon)).  Many older texts use $\varepsilon$ rather than $\in$.